# Array.prototype.filter not returning RegExp results

Tags: javascript

Probably missing something simple here, but still scratching my head about why my list of found items is always returning empty.

```
const words = ['apps', 'apples', 'bands', 'bannanas', 'cards', 'cantaloupes'];
const str = 'app';
const re = new RegExp(str, 'gi');

function partial(element) {
  console.log('partial', element, re.test(element))
  return re.test(element)
}

const found = words.filter(partial);

console.log(found);  // []?
```

In this example, if you look at the logs of `partial`, you see the two words 'apps' and 'apples' returning true, so AFAIK, the result in `found` should be `['apps', 'apples']`, right?

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/95nyxuLa/) too.

Comment: The best solution for your case is to just remove the `'g'` flag. You don't need a global regex if you only want to know if there is at least one match.

Comment: remove the log. test() is not a pure function.